# How to store sets of new list in a 2d list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list `path`. Initially, it looks like this:

`path = [2, 1, 3, 0]`

I will have to run many operations on `path` in different steps of my process. But I have to store the contents of `path` after each step. I mean,

```
path = [2, 1, 3, 0]

path.pop() # need to store

path.pop() # same

path.append(9) # same

path.append(5) # same
```

So, after each of these steps path will look like this:

```
path = [2, 1, 3, 0]

path = [2, 1, 3]

path = [2, 1]

path = [2, 1, 9]

path = [2, 1, 9, 5]
```

As I need each of these so I want to store them in a 2D list. Therefore, in the end, the 2D list will look like this:

But the problem is, initially I don't know how large `custom_list` can grow? It's decided only at runtime. So what I thought is that after each step I will append the `path` to my `custom_list` so when the process is finished `custom_list` will store all the `path's` content as mentioned above. Like this:

`custom_list = [[2, 1, 3, 0], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 1, 9], [2, 1, 9, 5]]`

But for this `.append` does not work. How to solve this problem?

Also is this efficient to implement this with `list` or should I choose any other way i.e. `numpy array` or anything else? If so then kindly mention and explain

**Edit**
Code:

```
list = [2,1,3,0]
my_list = [[]]
my_list.append(list)
list.pop()
list.pop()
list.append(9)
my_list.append(list)
list.append(5)
my_list.append(list)
my_list
>>>[[], [2, 1, 9, 5], [2, 1, 9, 5], [2, 1, 9, 5]]
```

Comment: still not clear what u asking, you can append list in list, whats the problem better to post the code and expected result in clear

Comment: appending a list within a list doesn't give the format like `custom_list` as I mentioned. It just adds like this:
`custom_list = [2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1 ,3]

Comment: post the code also

Comment: posted the codes

Comment: `my_list.append(list)` appends the same list over and over again.

Comment: This is my question!! What should I use to get the desired result as I mentioned.

Comment: @sphoenix just check answer below , let me know if works for u

Answer (score 2):

Would be better to use an immutable collection (create a `tuple` for each state you want to track):

```
list = [2,1,3,0]
my_list = [()]
my_list.append(tuple(list))
list.pop()
list.pop()
list.append(9)
my_list.append(tuple(list))
list.append(5)
my_list.append(tuple(list))
my_list
# produces [(), (2, 1, 3, 0), (2, 1, 9), (2, 1, 9, 5)]
```

Your problem is that `list` is being modified in place, and then `my_list` is just containing multiple references to the same list. `tuple` cannot be modified in place. Each addition is a completely new instance.

If for some reason you need to stick with lists, you can use `list[:]` to create a copy:

```
my_list.append(list[:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `copy.deepcopy`.
Whenever you doing appending and poping all operation performing on list so after lastoperation  whatever the list have values its printing the same

```
In [10]: path=[1,2,3,4]

In [11]: path2=path

In [12]: path.pop()
Out[12]: 4

In [13]: path2
Out[13]: [1, 2, 3]

In [14]: #using deepcopy

In [15]: import copy

In [16]: path=[1,2,3,4]

In [17]: path2=copy.deepcopy(path)

In [18]: path.pop()
Out[18]: 4

In [19]: path2
Out[19]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Modified your code :

```
  import copy
    list = [2,1,3,0]
    my_list = [] #take the inly list
    my_list.append(copy.deepcopy(list))
    list.pop()
    list.pop()
    list.append(9)
    my_list.append(copy.deepcopy(list))
    list.append(5)
    my_list.append(copy.deepcopy(list))
    print(my_list)
```

result:

```
[[2, 1, 3, 0], [2, 1, 9], [2, 1, 9, 5]]
```

Comment: `deepcopy` is only necessary if the list contains objects. If its just a list of `ints` there is no need to import anything as you can use `list.copy()`

Comment: thanks for suggestion, i just think about overall concept that can help

Answer (score 1):

use `path[:]` or `path.copy()` to make a copy

```
cusls = []
path = [2, 1, 3, 0]
cusls.append(path[:])
path.pop() # need to store
cusls.append(path[:])
path.pop() # same
cusls.append(path[:])
path.append(9) # same
cusls.append(path[:])
path.append(5) # same
cusls.append(path[:])

cusls
Out[25]: [[2, 1, 3, 0], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 1, 9], [2, 1, 9, 5]]
```